# Regarding Datatable

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a VB.NET migration project in which they are using AXF1Book to bind the data based on tab control selection.

As a replacement I thought that datatable or dataset would serve this purpose. Datatable rows and columns depend on the tab control selection.

```
nrows     =    ubound(arrtask) + 1
grd(nTabcount).col    =    0
grd(ntabcount).rows   =   nrows
```

Here tab count is nothing but the tab index we are selecting in tab control

What I would like to know is:

- How to set datatable rows and columns count based on a value. Say if the value is coming as 5, I have to set number of rows and columns to 5
- How to set the data dynamically after setting rows and columns count.

Comment: Please would you make it clearer what your actual question is.

Comment: My actual question is , 1)How to set datatable rows and columns count based on a value.Say if the value is coming as 5,i hve to set no.of rows and columns to 5 2) How to set the data dynamically after setting rows and columns count

Comment: I edited your comment into the question. Please feel free to edit it as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
Imports System.Data
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim dt As New DataTable()

        For cols As Integer = 0 To 1
            dt.Columns.Add("Col" & cols.ToString(), GetType(Int16))
        Next


        For rows As Integer = 0 To 4
            dt.Rows.Add()
        Next

    End Sub

End Module
​
```